# Getting total request count to a cosmosDb using Log Analytics logs

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-log-analytics

In Azure you can see how many requests have been made against a *CosmosDB* in the overview tab of the *cosmosDb*. I want to get that same number (total requests) using Log Analytics Diagnostic logs, but I am having trouble knowing which logs to count, since there are more logs than total requests.

Around March I used a logic that if a log had a full self-link (with database id/name and collection id/name) in requestResourceId_s field then I would count it. This seemed to work and the numbers added up, but when I revisited this a while back I noticed this doesn't work anymore. Then I tried filtering the logs with `collectionName_s != ""`, `requestLength_s != "0"`, `requestCharge_s != "0.000000"`, using the distinct operator on the activityId and combining the mentioned filters in different combinations. But it always returns the wrong numbers and I cant seem to find the Total Request Count.

```
AzureDiagnostics
| extend requestDatabaseId = extract("(^(/dbs/.*?)/)", 1, requestResourceId_s) 
| extend requestCollectionId = extract("((/colls/.*?)/)", 1, requestResourceId_s)
| where requestDatabaseId != "" and requestCollectionId != ""
```

This is the main point of the query I used to use to get the Total request count. For instance, it will count a log that has    `/dbs/master/colls/master/docs" in requestResourceId_s`

For instance, if I see there have been 97 total request, with my old logic there are now 326 logs that get counted.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

AFAIK you should use the below Kusto query to get the total number of requests made.

```
AzureMetrics | where MetricName == "TotalRequests"
```

Pre-requisite for the above thing to work is to turn on logging using diagnostic setting as explained in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/logging#turn-on-logging-in-the-azure-portal) document. Make sure you tick the 'Requests' box under Metric section as highlighted in below screenshot.

[image]

Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftdocumentdbdatabaseaccounts) document to know what all metrics are currently supported. Should supported metrics for any Azure resource changes in future then the information on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-metric-near-real-time%20document) would probably be updated.

Hope this helps!! Cheers!!

Comment: But is it possible to get the total request count only from AzureDiagnostics tab? Since my end goal is going to involve seeing how many request have been made on  each database and collection. And some logs have this info, only I can't find which logs I can count. The numbers just seem to never add up.